# Linear transformation example using trig functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

[image]

In this example, what gets us from:

$$= \begin{bmatrix} r\cos\theta \cos\alpha - r \sin\theta \sin\alpha \\ r \sin\theta \cos\alpha + r\cos\theta \sin\alpha \end{bmatrix}$$

to

$$= \begin{bmatrix} r\cos(\theta + \alpha) \\ r\sin(\theta + \alpha \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: To produce $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, $\cot x$, type \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, and \cot x, respectively, when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 1):

These are the [angle sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities):
$$
\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\beta\cos\alpha\\
\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta
$$

[image]